# Android APK with Watchface as library in it can't be installed because of "missing feature: watch"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, wear-os

I am currently trying to program a Wear OS watch face. I first compiled the app just with the watch face in it but couldn't install it on my Android smartphone (Android 6.0). So I created an additional mobile module and added the exiting wear module as an Android library. The mobile module contains a blank activity. Now I still can't install the app on my smartphone and when I want to test the app with an AVD it says "missing feature: watch"

Here's the **build.gradle of the whole project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's the **build.gradle of the mobile module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.leinequell.nixiesmart"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':wear')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Here's the **build.gradle of the wear library:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'

    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
}
```

Thank you all for the help. I am not a professional so the answer could be extremely obvious and easy to find. Also I am not a native English speaker so I am sorry if the grammar etc isn't perfect. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "couldn't install it on my android smartphone" ? What was the result of the compilation ?

Comment: On my real Smartphone It just said: Wont be installed. And it compiled just fine but i can only run the app over the watch emulator but not over the Smartphone Emulator so its impossible for me to test the mobile module

Answer (score 0):

what the error message `missing feature: watch` is trying to tell is ...

that you should run the application on an emulator with [Wear OS](https://wearos.google.com)  or a smartwatch.

when having a `:mobile` and `:wear` module, the run configurations should reflect that.